# Adding C wire to WiFi thermostat

Tags: wiring, installation, thermostat-c-wire, wifi

I’m trying to add c wire to furnace to run a WiFi thermostat but don’t know where to hook up c wire to get power to turn on thermostat i have 2 extra wires just don’t know where to put one them to get power[image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 3):

## Look for the junction of brown wires and attach your C wire to that

On the wiring diagram for your furnace, the brown wires are all C wires, and they come together at a junction that should be somewhere near where the mains wires come in.  Connect your C wire (which can be any unused wire in the thermostat cable) to that junction, perhaps with a length of extension wire (brown stranded #14 THHN/AWM will do the trick), and you'll be good to go.

Comment: According to the diagram, there should be a brown `C` wire near the other thermostat connections.